# ListDensityPlot change the colour scheme

Tags: plotting

I have used below syntax to generate the list density plot of the list uzL1Mo1 list.

```
ListDensityPlot[uzL1Mo1, AspectRatio -> 1/Sqrt[3], PlotLegends -> True]
```

I have edited the question by adding the data as per the comment below. Corresponding data is below stated

```
    {{27.8771, 48.1843, -0.61336}, {25.2718, 43.3709, -0.59442}, 
      {27.964, 
      45.0255, -0.60556}, {30.6562, 46.6801, -0.60948}, {33.3483, 
      48.3348, -0.60572}, {22.6665, 38.5575, -0.5572}, {25.3586, 
      40.2121, -0.57634}, {28.0508, 41.8667, -0.5904}, {30.743, 
      43.5213, -0.59798}, {33.4352, 45.1759, -0.59827}, {36.1274, 
      46.8306, -0.59114}, {38.8196, 48.4852, -0.57707}, {20.0611, 
      33.7441, -0.51274}, {22.7533, 35.3987, -0.53333}, {25.4455, 
      37.0533, -0.55284}, {28.1377, 38.7079, -0.56891}, {30.8299, 
      40.3625, -0.5796}, {33.522, 42.0171, -0.58371}, {36.2142, 
      43.6718, -0.58074}, {38.9064, 45.3264, -0.5709}, {41.5986, 
      46.981, -0.5551}, {44.2908, 48.6356, -0.53499}, {17.4558, 
      28.9307, -0.47725}, {20.148, 30.5853, -0.49079}, {22.8401, 
      32.2399, -0.50781}, {25.5323, 33.8945, -0.52595}, {28.2245, 
      35.5491, -0.54271}, {30.9167, 37.2037, -0.55572}, {33.6089, 
      38.8583, -0.56317}, {36.3011, 40.5129, -0.56409}, {38.9932, 
         42.1676, -0.55838}, {41.6854, 43.8222, -0.54674}, 
      {44.3776, 
       45.4768, -0.53063}, {47.0698, 47.1314, -0.51212}, {49.762, 
       48.786, -0.49356}, {14.8504, 24.1172, -0.46503}, {17.5426, 
       25.7718, -0.46517}, {20.2348, 27.4265, -0.47162}, {22.927, 
       29.0811, -0.4833}, {25.6192, 30.7357, -0.49831}, {28.3114, 
       32.3903, -0.51419}, {31.0035, 34.0449, -0.52832}, {33.6957, 
       35.6995, -0.53839}, {36.3879, 37.3541, -0.54281}, {39.0801, 
       39.0088, -0.54095}, {41.7723, 40.6634, -0.53325}, {44.4645, 
       42.318, -0.52101}, {47.1566, 43.9726, -0.5062}, {49.8488, 
       45.6272, -0.49113}, {52.541, 47.2818, -0.47806}, {55.2332, 
       48.9364, -0.46892}, {12.2451, 19.3038, -0.48123}, {14.9373, 
       20.9584, -0.46695}, {17.6295, 22.613, -0.45871}, {20.3216, 
       24.2677, -0.45727}, {23.0138, 25.9223, -0.46235}, {25.706, 
       27.5769, -0.47269}, {28.3982, 29.2315, -0.48615}, {31.0904, 
          30.8861, -0.50005}, {33.7826, 32.5407, -0.51172}, 
       {36.4748, 
       34.1953, -0.51901}, {39.1669, 35.8499, -0.52065}, {41.8591, 
       37.5046,
      -0.51656}, {44.5513, 39.1592, -0.50781}, {47.2435, 
      40.8138, -0.49628}, {49.9357, 42.4684, -0.48428}, {52.6279, 
      44.123, -0.47419}, {55.32, 45.7776, -0.46794}, {58.0122, 
      47.4322, -0.46681}, {60.7044, 49.0868, -0.47134}, {9.63976, 
      14.4904, -0.51901}, {12.3319, 16.145, -0.49529}, {15.0241, 
      17.7996, -0.47433}, {17.7163, 19.4542, -0.45839}, {20.4085, 
      21.1088, -0.44909}, {23.1007, 22.7635, -0.447}, {25.7929, 
      24.4181, -0.45164}, {28.485, 26.0727, -0.46141}, {31.1772, 
      27.7273, -0.47382}, {33.8694, 29.3819, -0.48598}, {36.5616, 
      31.0365, -0.49529}, {39.2538, 32.6911, -0.49988}, {41.946, 
      34.3458, -0.49906}, {44.6382, 36.0004, -0.49342}, {47.3303, 
      37.655, -0.48461}, {50.0225, 39.3096, -0.47498}, {52.7147, 
      40.9642, -0.46703}, {55.4069, 42.6188, -0.46294}, {58.0991, 
      44.2734, -0.46408}, {60.7913, 45.928, -0.47094}, {63.4834, 
      47.5827, -0.48325}, {66.1756, 49.2373, -0.49988}, {7.03442, 
      9.67698, -0.56317}, {9.7266, 11.3316, -0.53839}, {12.4188, 
      12.9862, -0.51172}, {15.111, 14.6408, -0.48598}, {17.8032, 
      16.2954, -0.46386}, {20.4953, 17.95, -0.44759}, {23.1875, 
      19.6047, -0.43858}, {25.8797, 21.2593, -0.43714}, {28.5719, 
      22.9139, -0.44238}, {31.2641, 24.5685, -0.45223}, {33.9563, 
      26.2231, -0.46386}, {36.6484, 27.8777, -0.47433}, {39.3406, 
      29.5323, -0.48123}, {42.0328, 31.1869, -0.48325}, {44.725, 
      32.8416, -0.48037}, {47.4172, 34.4962, -0.47382}, {50.1094, 
      36.1508, -0.46583}, {52.8015, 37.8054, -0.45905}, {55.4937, 
      39.46, -0.45593}, {58.1859, 41.1146, -0.45815}, {60.8781, 
      42.7692, -0.46637}, {63.5703, 44.4238, -0.48037}, {66.2625, 
      46.0785, -0.49906}, {68.9547, 47.7331, -0.52065}, {71.6468, 
      49.3877, -0.54281}, {4.42908, 4.86356, -0.59798}, {7.12126, 
      6.51817, -0.5796}, {9.81345, 8.17278, -0.55572}, {12.5056, 
      9.8274, -0.52832}, {15.1978, 11.482, -0.50005}, {17.89, 
      13.1366, -0.47382}, {20.5822, 14.7912, -0.45223}, {23.2744, 
      16.4458, -0.43734}, {25.9666, 18.1005, -0.43022}, {28.6587, 
      19.7551, -0.43071}, {31.3509, 21.4097, -0.43734}, {34.0431, 
      23.0643, -0.44759}, {36.7353, 24.7189, -0.45839}, {39.4275, 
      26.3735, -0.46695}, {42.1197, 28.0281, -0.47134}, {44.8118, 
      29.6828, -0.47094}, {47.504, 31.3374, -0.46637}, {50.1962, 
      32.992, -0.45951}, {52.8884, 34.6466, -0.45303}, {55.5806, 
      36.3012, -0.44963}, {58.2728, 37.9558, -0.45145}, {60.9649, 
      39.6104, -0.45951}, {63.6571, 41.265, -0.47382}, {66.3493, 
      42.9197, -0.49342}, {69.0415, 44.5743, -0.51656}, {71.7337, 
      46.2289, -0.54095}, {74.4259, 47.8835, -0.56409}, {77.1181, 
      49.5381, -0.58371}, {1.82374, 0.0501398, -0.61336}, 
      {4.51592, 
      1.70475, -0.60556}, {7.20811, 3.35937, -0.5904}, {9.90029, 
      5.01398, -0.56891}, {12.5925, 6.66859, -0.54271}, {15.2847, 
      8.3232, -0.51419}, {17.9768, 9.97782, -0.48615}, {20.669, 
      11.6324, -0.46141}, {23.3612, 13.287, -0.44238}, {26.0534, 
      14.9417, -0.43071}, {28.7456, 16.5963, -0.42692}, {31.4378, 
      18.2509, -0.43022}, {34.1299, 19.9055, -0.43858}, {36.8221, 
       21.5601, -0.44909}, {39.5143, 23.2147, -0.45871}, {42.2065, 
      24.8693, -0.46503}, {44.8987, 26.5239, -0.46681}, {47.5909, 
      28.1786, -0.46408}, {50.2831, 29.8332, -0.45815}, {52.9752, 
      31.4878, -0.45145}, {55.6674, 33.1424, -0.44681}, {58.3596, 
      34.797, -0.44681}, {61.0518, 36.4516, -0.45303}, {63.744, 
      38.1062, -0.46583}, {66.4362, 39.7608, -0.48461}, {69.1283, 
      41.4155, -0.50781}, {71.8205, 43.0701, -0.53325}, {74.5127, 
      44.7247, -0.55838}, {77.2049, 46.3793, -0.58074}, {79.8971, 
      48.0339, -0.59827}, {82.5893, 49.6885, -0.60948}, {7.29495, 
      0.200559, -0.59442}, {9.98714, 1.85517, -0.57634}, {12.6793, 
       3.50978, -0.55284}, {15.3715, 5.1644, -0.52595}, {18.0637, 
     6.81901, -0.49831}, {20.7559, 8.47362, -0.47269}, {23.4481, 
     10.1282, -0.45164}, {26.1402, 11.7828, -0.43714}, {28.8324, 
     13.4375, -0.43022}, {31.5246, 15.0921, -0.43071}, {34.2168, 
     16.7467, -0.43714}, {36.909, 18.4013, -0.447}, {39.6012, 
     20.0559, -0.45727}, {42.2933, 21.7105, -0.46517}, {44.9855, 
     23.3651, -0.46892}, {47.6777, 25.0198, -0.46794}, {50.3699, 
     26.6744, -0.46294}, {53.0621, 28.329, -0.45593}, {55.7543, 
     29.9836, -0.44963}, {58.4465, 31.6382, -0.44681}, {61.1386, 
     33.2928, -0.44963}, {63.8308, 34.9474, -0.45905}, {66.523, 
     36.602, -0.47498}, {69.2152, 38.2567, -0.49628}, {71.9074, 
     39.9113, -0.52101}, {74.5996, 41.5659, -0.54674}, {77.2917, 
     43.2205, -0.5709}, {79.9839, 44.8751, -0.59114}, {82.6761, 
     46.5297, -0.60572}, {12.7662, 0.350978, -0.5572}, {15.4583, 
     2.00559, -0.53333}, {18.1505, 3.6602, -0.50781}, {20.8427, 
     5.31482, -0.4833}, {23.5349, 6.96943, -0.46235}, {26.2271, 
      8.62404, -0.447}, {28.9193, 10.2787, -0.43858}, {31.6115, 
     11.9333, -0.43734}, {34.3036, 13.5879, -0.44238}, {36.9958, 
     15.2425, -0.45164}, {39.688, 16.8971, -0.46235}, {42.3802, 
      18.5517, -0.47162}, {45.0724, 20.2063, -0.47725}, {47.7646, 
   , -0.47806}, {50.4567, 23.5156, -0.47419}, {53.1489, 
     25.1702, -0.46703}, {55.8411, 26.8248, -0.45905}, {58.5333, 
     28.4794, -0.45303}, {61.2255, 30.134, -0.45145}, {63.9177, 
     31.7886, -0.45593}, {66.6098, 33.4432, -0.46703}, {69.302, 
      35.0978, -0.48428}, {71.9942, 36.7525, -0.5062}, {74.6864, 
      38.4071, -0.53063}, {77.3786, 40.0617, -0.5551}, {80.0708, 
     41.7163, -0.57707}, {18.2374, 0.501398, -0.51274}, {20.9296, 
     2.15601, -0.49079}, {23.6217, 3.81062, -0.47162}, {26.3139, 
     5.46524, -0.45727}, {29.0061, 7.11985, -0.44909}, {31.6983, 
     8.77446, -0.44759}, {34.3905, 10.4291, -0.45223}, {37.0827, 
     12.0837, -0.46141}, {39.7749, 13.7383, -0.47269}, {42.467, 
     15.3929, -0.4833}, {45.1592, 17.0475, -0.49079}, {47.8514, 
     18.7021, -0.49356}, {50.5436, 20.3568, -0.49113}, {53.2358, 
     22.0114, -0.48428}, {55.928, 23.666, -0.47498}, {58.6201, 
     25.3206, -0.46583}, {61.3123, 26.9752, -0.45951}, {64.0045, 
     28.6298, -0.45815}, {66.6967, 30.2844, -0.46294}, {69.3889, 
     31.939, -0.47419}, {72.0811, 33.5937, -0.49113}, {74.7732, 
      35.2483, -0.51212}, {77.4654, 36.9029, -0.53499}, {23.7086, 
    0.651817, -0.47725}, {26.4008, 2.30643, -0.46517}, {29.093, 
    3.96104, -0.45871}, {31.7851, 5.61566, -0.45839}, {34.4773, 
    7.27027, -0.46386}, {37.1695, 8.92488, -0.47382}, {39.8617, 
     10.5795, -0.48615}, {42.5539, 12.2341, -0.49831}, {45.2461, 
    13.8887, -0.50781}, {47.9382, 15.5433, -0.51274}, {50.6304, 
    17.1979, -0.51212}, {53.3226, 18.8526, -0.5062}, {56.0148, 
    20.5072, -0.49628}, {58.707, 22.1618, -0.48461}, {61.3992, 
    23.8164, -0.47382}, {64.0914, 25.471, -0.46637}, {66.7835, 
     27.1256, -0.46408}, {69.4757, 28.7802, -0.46794}, {72.1679, 
    30.4348, -0.47806}, {74.8601, 32.0895, -0.49356}, {29.1798, 
    0.802237, -0.46503}, {31.872, 2.45685, -0.46695}, {34.5642, 
    4.11146, -0.47433}, {37.2564, 5.76608, -0.48598}, {39.9485, 
    7.42069, -0.50005}, {42.6407, 9.0753, -0.51419}, {45.3329, 
    10.7299, -0.52595}, {48.0251, 12.3845, -0.53333}, {50.7173, 
    14.0391, -0.53499}, {53.4095, 15.6938, -0.53063}, {56.1016, 
    17.3484, -0.52101}, {58.7938, 19.003, -0.50781}, {61.486, 
    20.6576, -0.49342}, {64.1782, 22.3122, -0.48037}, {66.8704, 
    23.9668, -0.47094}, {69.5626, 25.6214, -0.46681}, {72.2548, 
    27.276, -0.46892}, {34.651, 0.952656, -0.48123}, {37.3432, 
    2.60727, -0.49529}, {40.0354, 4.26188, -0.51172}, {42.7276, 
    5.91649, -0.52832}, {45.4198, 7.57111, -0.54271}, {48.1119, 
    9.22572, -0.55284}, {50.8041, 10.8803, -0.5572}, {53.4963, 
    12.5349, -0.5551}, {56.1885, 14.1896, -0.54674}, {58.8807, 
    15.8442, -0.53325}, {61.5729, 17.4988, -0.51656}, {64.265, 
    19.1534, -0.49906}, {66.9572, 20.808, -0.48325}, {69.6494, 
    22.4626, -0.47134}, {40.1222, 1.10308, -0.51901}, {42.8144, 
    2.75769, -0.53839}, {45.5066, 4.4123, -0.55572}, {48.1988, 
     6.06691, -0.56891}, {50.891, 7.72153, -0.57634}, {53.5832, 
   9.37614,
   -0.57707}, {56.2753, 11.0308, -0.5709}, {58.9675, 
   12.6854, -0.55838}, {61.6597, 14.34, -0.54095}, {64.3519, 
   15.9946, -0.52065}, {67.0441, 17.6492, -0.49988}, {45.5934, 
    1.25349, -0.56317}, {48.2856, 2.90811, -0.5796}, {50.9778, 
   4.56272, -0.5904}, {53.67, 6.21733, -0.59442}, {56.3622, 
   7.87195, -0.59114}, {59.0544, 9.52656, -0.58074}, {61.7465, 
   11.1812, -0.56409}, {64.4387, 12.8358, -0.54281}, {51.0647, 
   1.40391, -0.59798}, {53.7568, 3.05853, -0.60556}, {56.449, 
   4.71314, -0.60572}, {59.1412, 6.36775, -0.59827}, {61.8334, 
    8.02237, -0.58371}, {56.5359, 1.55433, -0.61336}, {59.2281, 
  3.20895, -0.60948}}
```

[image]

I want to make a new plot if the magnitude of the third element (ex: -0.61336)in each list is less than 0.79 to be dark red. otherwise green. Can you please assist me with this.
Basically what I'm trying to change the plot legend in a new colour scheme as pen in below attached figure. Thanks for the help

[image]

Comment: Please post the data by text,not the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry about that. When trying to type the table it gives a formating error. I tried to fix that but couldn't

Comment: You can post the data just as  above code,enclose it by  ```  data    ````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    {{30.5693, 49.7387, 0.6134}, {27.7034, 45.0757, 0.6057}, {30.4825, 
    46.5799, 0.6095}, {33.2615, 48.0841, 0.6056}, {36.0405, 49.5882, 
    0.5944}, {24.8376, 40.4127, 0.5771}, {27.6166, 41.9169, 
    0.5911}, {30.3956, 43.4211, 0.5983}, {33.1747, 44.9252, 
    0.598}, {35.9537, 46.4294, 0.5904}, {38.7327, 47.9336, 
    0.5763}, {41.5117, 49.4378, 0.5572}, {21.9717, 35.7497, 
     0.535}, {24.7507, 37.2539, 0.5551}, {27.5298, 38.7581, 
    0.5709}, {30.3088, 40.2622, 0.5807}, {33.0878, 41.7664, 
    0.5837}, {35.8668, 43.2706, 0.5796}, {38.6459, 44.7748, 
    0.5689}, {41.4249, 46.279, 0.5528}, {44.2039, 47.7832, 
    0.5333}, {46.983, 49.2874, 0.5127}, {19.1058, 31.0867, 
    0.4936}, {21.8849, 32.5909, 0.5121}, {24.6639, 34.0951, 
    0.5306}, {27.4429, 35.5992, 0.5467}, {30.2219, 37.1034, 
    0.5584}, {33.001, 38.6076, 0.5641}, {35.78, 40.1118, 
    0.5632}, {38.559, 41.616, 0.5557}, {41.3381, 43.1202, 
    0.5427}, {44.1171, 44.6244, 0.526}, {46.8961, 46.1286, 
    0.5078}, {49.6751, 47.6328, 0.4908}, {52.4542, 49.137, 
    0.4772}, {16.24, 26.4237, 0.4689}, {19.019, 27.9279, 
    0.4781}, {21.798, 29.4321, 0.4911}, {24.577, 30.9362, 
    0.5062}, {27.3561, 32.4404, 0.521}, {30.1351, 33.9446, 
    0.5332}, {32.9141, 35.4488, 0.5409}, {35.6932, 36.953, 
   0.5428}, {38.4722, 38.4572, 0.5384}, {41.2512, 39.9614, 
   0.5283}, {44.0302, 41.4656, 0.5142}, {46.8093, 42.9698, 
   0.4983}, {49.5883, 44.474, 0.4833}, {52.3673, 45.9782, 
   0.4716}, {55.1464, 47.4824, 0.4652}, {57.9254, 48.9866, 
   0.465}, {13.3741, 21.7607, 0.4713}, {16.1531, 23.2649, 
  0.4668}, {18.9321, 24.7691, 0.4679}, {21.7112, 26.2732, 
   0.4742}, {24.4902, 27.7774, 0.4843}, {27.2692, 29.2816, 
  0.4963}, {30.0483, 30.7858, 0.5078}, {32.8273, 32.29, 
  0.5166}, {35.6063, 33.7942, 0.5206}, {38.3853, 35.2984, 
  0.519}, {41.1644, 36.8026, 0.5117}, {43.9434, 38.3068, 
  0.5}, {46.7224, 39.811, 0.4861}, {49.5015, 41.3152, 
  0.4727}, {52.2805, 42.8194, 0.4623}, {55.0595, 44.3236, 
  0.4573}, {57.8385, 45.8278, 0.4587}, {60.6176, 47.332, 
  0.4669}, {63.3966, 48.8362, 0.4812}, {10.5082, 17.0977, 
  0.4999}, {13.2872, 18.6019, 0.4832}, {16.0663, 20.1061, 
  0.4709}, {18.8453, 21.6102, 0.4641}, {21.6243, 23.1144, 
  0.4629}, {24.4033, 24.6186, 0.467}, {27.1824, 26.1228, 
  0.475}, {29.9614, 27.627, 0.4846}, {32.7404, 29.1312, 
  0.4934}, {35.5195, 30.6354, 0.4991}, {38.2985, 32.1396, 
  0.4999}, {41.0775, 33.6438, 0.4953}, {43.8566, 35.148, 
  0.486}, {46.6356, 36.6522, 0.4738}, {49.4146, 38.1564, 
  0.4614}, {52.1936, 39.6606, 0.4516}, {54.9727, 41.1648, 
  0.447}, {57.7517, 42.669, 0.4491}, {60.5307, 44.1732, 
  0.4584}, {63.3098, 45.6773, 0.4743}, {66.0888, 47.1815, 
  0.4953}, {68.8678, 48.6857, 0.519}, {7.64233, 12.4347, 
  0.5428}, {10.4214, 13.9389, 0.5206}, {13.2004, 15.4431, 
  0.4991}, {15.9794, 16.9472, 0.4804}, {18.7584, 18.4514, 
 0.4664}, {21.5375, 19.9556, 0.4581}, {24.3165, 21.4598, 
 0.4559}, {27.0955, 22.964, 0.459}, {29.8746, 24.4682, 
 0.4658}, {32.6536, 25.9724, 0.4738}, {35.4326, 27.4766, 
 0.4804}, {38.2116, 28.9808, 0.4832}, {40.9907, 30.485, 
  0.4812}, {43.7697, 31.9892, 0.4743}, {46.5487, 33.4934, 
 0.4639}, {49.3278, 34.9976, 0.4522}, {52.1068, 36.5018, 
0.4424}, {54.8858, 38.006, 0.4371}, {57.6649, 39.5102, 
0.4386}, {60.4439, 41.0143, 0.4476}, {63.2229, 42.5185, 
 0.4639}, {66.0019, 44.0227, 0.486}, {68.781, 45.5269, 
0.5117}, {71.56, 47.0311, 0.5384}, {74.339, 48.5353, 
 0.5632}, {4.77646, 7.77167, 0.5837}, {7.55548, 9.27586, 
 0.5641}, {10.3345, 10.7801, 0.5409}, {13.1135, 12.2842, 
 0.5166}, {15.8926, 13.7884, 0.4934}, {18.6716, 15.2926, 
0.4738}, {21.4506, 16.7968, 0.4595}, {24.2297, 18.301, 
 0.4514}, {27.0087, 19.8052, 0.4496}, {29.7877, 21.3094, 
 0.453}, {32.5667, 22.8136, 0.4595}, {35.3458, 24.3178, 
 0.4664}, {38.1248, 25.822, 0.4709}, {40.9038, 27.3262, 
  0.4713}, {43.6829, 28.8304, 0.4669}, {46.4619, 30.3346, 
 0.4584}, {49.2409, 31.8388, 0.4476}, {52.0199, 33.343, 
 0.4373}, {54.799, 34.8472, 0.4307}, {57.578, 36.3513, 
 0.4302}, {60.357, 37.8555, 0.4373}, {63.1361, 39.3597, 
 0.4522}, {65.9151, 40.8639, 0.4738}, {68.6941, 42.3681, 
 0.5}, {71.4732, 43.8723, 0.5283}, {74.2522, 45.3765, 
 0.5557}, {77.0312, 46.8807, 0.5796}, {79.8102, 48.3849, 
0.598}, {1.91058, 3.10867, 0.6095}, {4.68961, 4.61286, 
 0.5983}, {7.46864, 6.11705, 0.5807}, {10.2477, 7.62125, 
 0.5584}, {13.0267, 9.12544, 0.5332}, {15.8057, 10.6296, 
 0.5078}, {18.5848, 12.1338, 0.4846}, {21.3638, 13.638, 
 0.4658}, {24.1428, 15.1422, 0.453}, {26.9218, 16.6464, 
 0.4468}, {29.7009, 18.1506, 0.4468}, {32.4799, 19.6548, 
 0.4514}, {35.2589, 21.159, 0.4581}, {38.038, 22.6632, 
 0.4641}, {40.817, 24.1674, 0.4668}, {43.596, 25.6716, 
 0.465}, {46.375, 27.1758, 0.4587}, {49.1541, 28.68, 
 0.4491}, {51.9331, 30.1842, 0.4386}, {54.7121, 31.6883, 
 0.4302}, {57.4912, 33.1925, 0.4269}, {60.2702, 34.6967, 
 0.4307}, {63.0492, 36.2009, 0.4424}, {65.8282, 37.7051, 
  0.4614}, {68.6073, 39.2093, 0.4861}, {71.3863, 40.7135, 
 0.5142}, {74.1653, 42.2177, 0.5427}, {76.9444, 43.7219, 
 0.5689}, {79.7234, 45.2261, 0.5904}, {82.5024, 46.7303, 
  0.6056}, {85.2815, 48.2345, 0.6134}, {4.60277, 1.45405, 
  0.6057}, {7.3818, 2.95825, 0.5911}, {10.1608, 4.46244, 
  0.5709}, {12.9399, 5.96663, 0.5467}, {15.7189, 7.47083, 
  0.521}, {18.4979, 8.97502, 0.4963}, {21.2769, 10.4792, 
  0.475}, {24.056, 11.9834, 0.459}, {26.835, 13.4876, 
  0.4496}, {29.614, 14.9918, 0.4468}, {32.3931, 16.496, 
  0.4496}, {35.1721, 18.0002, 0.4559}, {37.9511, 19.5044, 
  0.4629}, {40.7301, 21.0086, 0.4679}, {43.5092, 22.5128, 
  0.4689}, {46.2882, 24.017, 0.4652}, {49.0672, 25.5212, 
  0.4573}, {51.8463, 27.0253, 0.447}, {54.6253, 28.5295, 
  0.4371}, {57.4043, 30.0337, 0.4307}, {60.1833, 31.5379, 
  0.4302}, {62.9624, 33.0421, 0.4371}, {65.7414, 34.5463, 
  0.4516}, {68.5204, 36.0505, 0.4727}, {71.2995, 37.5547, 
  0.4983}, {74.0785, 39.0589, 0.526}, {76.8575, 40.5631, 
   0.5528}, {79.6365, 42.0673, 0.5763}, {82.4156, 43.5715, 
  0.5944}, {10.074, 1.30363, 0.5771}, {12.853, 2.80783, 
  0.5551}, {15.632, 4.31202, 0.5306}, {18.4111, 5.81621, 
  0.5062}, {21.1901, 7.32041, 0.4843}, {23.9691, 8.8246, 
  0.467}, {26.7482, 10.3288, 0.4559}, {29.5272, 11.833, 
  0.4514}, {32.3062, 13.3372, 0.453}, {35.0852, 14.8414, 
  0.459}, {37.8643, 16.3456, 0.467}, {40.6433, 17.8498, 
  0.4742}, {43.4223, 19.354, 0.4781}, {46.2014, 20.8582, 
   0.4772}, {48.9804, 22.3623, 0.4716}, {51.7594, 23.8665, 
  0.4623}, {54.5384, 25.3707, 0.4516}, {57.3175, 26.8749, 
  0.4424}, {60.0965, 28.3791, 0.4373}, {62.8755, 29.8833, 
  0.4386}, {65.6546, 31.3875, 0.447}, {68.4336, 32.8917, 
  0.4623}, {71.2126, 34.3959, 0.4833}, {73.9916, 35.9001, 
  0.5078}, {76.7707, 37.4043, 0.5333}, {79.5497, 38.9085, 
  0.5572}, {15.5452, 1.15322, 0.535}, {18.3242, 2.65741, 
   0.5121}, {21.1033, 4.1616, 0.4911}, {23.8823, 5.6658, 
  0.4742}, {26.6613, 7.16999, 0.4629}, {29.4403, 8.67418, 
  0.4581}, {32.2194, 10.1784, 0.4595}, {34.9984, 11.6826, 
  0.4658}, {37.7774, 13.1868, 0.475}, {40.5565, 14.691, 
  0.4843}, {43.3355, 16.1952, 0.4911}, {46.1145, 17.6993, 
  0.4936}, {48.8935, 19.2035, 0.4908}, {51.6726, 20.7077, 
  0.4833}, {54.4516, 22.2119, 0.4727}, {57.2306, 23.7161, 
  0.4614}, {60.0097, 25.2203, 0.4522}, {62.7887, 26.7245, 
  0.4476}, {65.5677, 28.2287, 0.4491}, {68.3467, 29.7329, 
  0.4573}, {71.1258, 31.2371, 0.4716}, {73.9048, 32.7413, 
  0.4908}, {76.6838, 34.2455, 0.5127}, {21.0164, 1.0028, 
  0.4936}, {23.7954, 2.50699, 0.4781}, {26.5745, 4.01118, 
  0.4679}, {29.3535, 5.51538, 0.4641}, {32.1325, 7.01957, 
   0.4664}, {34.9116, 8.52376, 0.4738}, {37.6906, 10.028, 
  0.4846}, {40.4696, 11.5322, 0.4963}, {43.2486, 13.0363, 
  0.5062}, {46.0277, 14.5405, 0.5121}, {48.8067, 16.0447, 
  0.5127}, {51.5857, 17.5489, 0.5078}, {54.3648, 19.0531, 
  0.4983}, {57.1438, 20.5573, 0.4861}, {59.9228, 22.0615, 
  0.4738}, {62.7018, 23.5657, 0.4639}, {65.4809, 25.0699, 
  0.4584}, {68.2599, 26.5741, 0.4587}, {71.0389, 28.0783, 
  0.4652}, {73.818, 29.5825, 0.4772}, {26.4876, 0.852376, 
  0.4689}, {29.2666, 2.35657, 0.4668}, {32.0457, 3.86076, 
  0.4709}, {34.8247, 5.36496, 0.4804}, {37.6037, 6.86915, 
  0.4934}, {40.3828, 8.37334, 0.5078}, {43.1618, 9.87754, 
   0.521}, {45.9408, 11.3817, 0.5306}, {48.7199, 12.8859, 
  0.535}, {51.4989, 14.3901, 0.5333}, {54.2779, 15.8943, 
   0.526}, {57.0569, 17.3985, 0.5142}, {59.836, 18.9027, 0.5}, {62.615,
   20.4069, 0.486}, {65.394, 21.9111, 0.4743}, {68.1731, 23.4153, 
  0.4669}, {70.9521, 24.9195, 0.465}, {31.9588, 0.701957, 
   0.4713}, {34.7379, 2.20615, 0.4832}, {37.5169, 3.71034, 
   0.4991}, {40.2959, 5.21454, 0.5166}, {43.0749, 6.71873, 
  0.5332}, {45.854, 8.22292, 0.5467}, {48.633, 9.72712, 
   0.5551}, {51.412, 11.2313, 0.5572}, {54.1911, 12.7355, 
  0.5528}, {56.9701, 14.2397, 0.5427}, {59.7491, 15.7439, 
  0.5283}, {62.5282, 17.2481, 0.5117}, {65.3072, 18.7523, 
  0.4953}, {68.0862, 20.2565, 0.4812}, {37.43, 0.551538, 
  0.4999}, {40.2091, 2.05573, 0.5206}, {42.9881, 3.55992, 
  0.5409}, {45.7671, 5.06412, 0.5584}, {48.5462, 6.56831, 
  0.5709}, {51.3252, 8.07251, 0.5771}, {54.1042, 9.5767, 
  0.5763}, {56.8832, 11.0809, 0.5689}, {59.6623, 12.5851, 
  0.5557}, {62.4413, 14.0893, 0.5384}, {65.2203, 15.5935, 
  0.519}, {42.9013, 0.401118, 0.5428}, {45.6803, 1.90531, 
  0.5641}, {48.4593, 3.40951, 0.5807}, {51.2383, 4.9137, 
  0.5911}, {54.0174, 6.41789, 0.5944}, {56.7964, 7.92209, 
  0.5904}, {59.5754, 9.42628, 0.5796}, {62.3545, 10.9305, 
  0.5632}, {48.3725, 0.250699, 0.5837}, {51.1515, 1.75489, 
   0.5983}, {53.9305, 3.25909, 0.6057}, {56.7096, 4.76328, 
   0.6056}, {59.4886, 6.26747, 0.598}, {53.8437, 0.10028, 
   0.6095}, {56.6227, 1.60447, 0.6134}}


  data = uzL2Mo1;
  default = If[# < 0.6, Darker[Red], Green] &;

  Manipulate[
   ListDensityPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1/Sqrt[3], PlotLegends -> True, 
   ColorFunction -> cf, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> (! (cf === default))], {{cf, default, 
   ColorFunction}, 
   Join[ColorData["Gradients"], {default, 
   Blend[{Darker[Red], Green}, #] &}]}]here
```

[image]

I get above attached figure. I needed this type of figure.
Just a quick question

## < 0.6

when we use this, how they just pick the third element of the list. Please explain if possible

Comment: Please include this as part of your question, not as an answer.

Comment: Refer to the docs for [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html). The argument for `ColorFunction` when used with `ListDensityPlot` is the function value, i.e., the third element of the data points.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = Table[
   With[{r = RandomReal[{0, 5}], t = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]}, {r Cos[t], 
     r Sin[t], Sin[r^2]/r^2}], {10^4}];
```

Use the option [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html)

```
default = If[# < 0.79, Darker[Red], Green] &;

Manipulate[
 ListDensityPlot[data,
  AspectRatio -> 1/Sqrt[3],
  PlotLegends -> True,
  ColorFunction -> cf,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> (! (cf === default))],
 {{cf, default, ColorFunction},
  Join[ColorData["Gradients"],
   {default, Blend[{Darker[Red], Green}, #] &}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment !!!